# Property 'entryDate' does not exist on type 'DocumentChange'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching data from Firestore using `.snapshotChanges()`. It has a timestamp field called `entryDate`. While importing data I am trying to change its format. For that I have to assign the `timestamp` to variable but getting error. Below is my code:

The error is here: `const timeinmillsecs = item.payload.entryDate.seconds * 1000;  // error on this line`

```
 this.firestore.collection('projects' , ref => ref
    .limit(10) 
    .orderBy('entryDate', 'desc')
    )
    .snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(response => {
    if(!response.length){
      console.log("no data available");
      return false; 
    }
    this.firstInResponse = response[0].payload.doc;
    this.lastInResponse = response[response.length - 1].payload.doc;
    console.log(this.firstInResponse);
    console.log(this.lastInResponse);
    this.tableData=[];  
    for(let item of response){
     const timeinmillsecs = item.payload.entryDate.seconds * 1000;  // error on this line
     ...
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I believe item.payload["entryDate"]["seconds"] will work for you

Comment: seconds is not part of array `(item.payload["entryDate"].seconds) * 1000;` even this is not working

Comment: You have to first parse - item.payload["entryDate"] into the specific type, what is the data type of entryDate?

Comment: In case you are using Firebase Timestamp -
(item.payload["entryDate"] as Timestamp).toMillis() will give you the milliseconds.

Comment: yes, its a timestamp, using above code, it is giving error on timestamp, says - `Cannot find name 'Timestamp'.ts`

Comment: Now after import timestamp from rxjs, its saying `Generic type 'Timestamp<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Comment: By Firebase Timestamp I meant [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) Please share in what format are you storing entryDate

Comment: saving in this format only

Comment: What is this format. Can you share some data?